# Nested tabs in tabs (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

i'm trying to nest two bootstrap tabs, but the first tab that should show a nested tab, shows the content of the two tabs one below the other. This is the code, i'm using jquery 1.11.1 and bootstrap, anyone has any idea on how to solve this mess?

```html
<ul id="general-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab-general" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>

    <li id="shipping_tab"><a href="#tab-shipping" data-toggle="tab">Shipping</a></li>



    <li><a href="#tab-options" data-toggle="tab">Options</a></li>

    <li><a href="#tab-specials" data-toggle="tab">Special prices</a></li>

    <li><a href="#tab-discounts" data-toggle="tab">Quantity discounts</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- general tab -->
<div class="tab-content ms-product">
    <div id="tab-general" class="tab-pane active">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="language-tabs">
            <li><a class="lang" data-toggle="tab" href="#language1"><img src="image/flags/gb.png" title="English" /> English</a></li>
            <li><a class="lang" data-toggle="tab" href="#language2"><img src="image/flags/it.png" title="Italiano" /> Italiano</a></li>
        </ul>


        <div class="ms-language-div" id="language1">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Name & Description</legend>
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="languages[1][product_name]" value="Agate and silver necklace" />
                        <p class="ms-note">Specify a name for your product</p>
                        <p class="error" id="error_product_name_1"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <!-- todo strip tags if rte disabled -->
                        <textarea name="languages[1][product_description]" class="form-control ">Integer et diam ut est vestibulum ullamcorper ac mattis quam. Integer felis felis, gravida vitae sapien vitae, semper fringilla enim. Quisque commodo nisl in ligula ultrices aliquam. Vestibulum non sem elementum, fringilla augue commodo, porttitor ipsum. Pellentesque ac pretium lacus, sed molestie nisl. Nulla fringilla eu nulla at varius. Nulla semper imperdiet orci, vel sodales arcu fringilla sed. Sed non urna justo. Etiam gravida, nunc in tincidunt tincidunt, nisl eros aliquet libero, sed molestie elit nulla scelerisque magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi convallis posuere aliquam.
                        </textarea>
                        <p class="ms-note">Describe your product</p>
                        <p class="error" id="error_product_description_1"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tags</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="languages[1][product_tags]" value="" />
                        <p class="ms-note">Specify tags for your product.</p>
                        <p class="error" id="error_product_tags_1"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div class="ms-language-div" id="language2">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Name & Description</legend>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="languages[2][product_name]" value="italiano" />
                        <p class="ms-note">Specify a name for your product</p>
                        <p class="error" id="error_product_name_2"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <!-- todo strip tags if rte disabled -->
                        <textarea name="languages[2][product_description]" class="form-control ">Integer et diam ut est vestibulum ullamcorper ac mattis quam. Integer felis felis, gravida vitae sapien vitae, semper fringilla enim. Quisque commodo nisl in ligula ultrices aliquam. Vestibulum non sem elementum, fringilla augue commodo, porttitor ipsum. Pellentesque ac pretium lacus, sed molestie nisl. Nulla fringilla eu nulla at varius. Nulla semper imperdiet orci, vel sodales arcu fringilla sed. Sed non urna justo. Etiam gravida, nunc in tincidunt tincidunt, nisl eros aliquet libero, sed molestie elit nulla scelerisque magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi convallis posuere aliquam.
                        </textarea>
                        <p class="ms-note">Describe your product</p>
                        <p class="error" id="error_product_description_2"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tags</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="languages[2][product_tags]" value="" />
                        <p class="ms-note">Specify tags for your product.</p>
                        <p class="error" id="error_product_tags_2"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Price & Attributes</legend>

            <div class="form-group required">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <span class="vertical-align: auto">$</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control inline" name="product_price" value="50"  />
                    <span class="vertical-align: auto"></span>
                    <p class="ms-note">Choose a price for your product</p>
                    <p class="error" id="error_product_price"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group required">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10" id="product_category_block">

                    <select class="form-control" name="product_category">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="299"  >Chairs</option>
  <input type="radio" name="product_enable_shipping" value="0" />
                    No      <p class="ms-note">Specify whether your product requires shipping</p>
                    <p class="error" id="error_product_enable_shipping"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="display: none">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Quantity</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_quantity" value="999" class="ffUnchangeable" />
                    <p class="ms-note">Specify the quantity of your product</p>
                    <p class="error" id="error_product_quantity"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="product_quantity" value="5" />

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Files</legend>

            <div class="form-group ">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Images</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <!--<input type="file" name="ms-file-addimages" id="ms-file-addimages" />-->
                    <a name="ms-file-addimages" id="ms-file-addimages" class="btn btn-primary"><span>Select images</span></a>
                    <p class="ms-note">Select images for your product. First image will be used as a thumbnail. You can change the order of the images by dragging them. Allowed extensions: png,jpg,jpeg</p>
                    <div class="error" id="error_product_image"></div>

                    <div class="image progress"></div>

                    <div class="product_image_files">
                        <div class="ms-image">
                            <input type="hidden" name="product_images[]" value="catalog/demo/samsung_tab_1.jpg" />
                            <img src="http://localhost/opencart/image/tmp/samsung_tab_1-100x100.jpg" />
                            <span class="ms-remove"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group ">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Downloads</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <!--<input type="file" name="ms-file-addfiles" id="ms-file-addfiles" />-->
                    <a name="ms-file-addfiles" id="ms-file-addfiles" class="btn btn-primary"><span>Select files</span></a>
                    <p class="ms-note">Upload files for your product. Allowed extensions: zip,rar,pdf</p>
                    <div class="error" id="error_product_download"></div>
                    <div class="download progress"></div>
                    <div class="product_download_files">
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: none">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="push_downloads" id="push_downloads" />
                        <label>Push updates to previous customers</label>
                        <p class="ms-note">Newly added and updated downloads will be made available to previous customers</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

    </div>

    <!-- data tab -->
    <div id="tab-data" class="tab-pane">
    </div>

    <!-- options tab -->
    <div id="tab-options" class="tab-pane"></div>


    <div id="tab-shipping" class="tab-pane"></div>

    <!-- specials tab -->
    <div id="tab-specials" class="tab-pane">
        <legend>Special prices</legend>
        <p class="error" id="error_specials"></p>

        <table class="list table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="required">*</span>Priority</td>
                    <td><span class="required">*</span>Price</td>
                    <td><span class="required">*</span>Start date</td>
                    <td><span class="required">*</span>End date</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <!-- sample row -->
                <tr class="ffSample">
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control inline" name="product_specials[0][priority]" value="" size="2" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control inline" name="product_specials[0][price]" value="" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group date">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control inline" name="product_specials[0][date_start]" value="" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group date">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control inline" name="product_specials[0][date_end]" value="" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><a class="ms-button-delete" title="Delete"></a></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary ffClone">Define a new special price</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- Quantity Discounts tab -->
    <div id="tab-discounts" class="tab-pane">
        <legend>Quantity discounts</legend>
        <p class="error" id="error_quantity_discounts"></p>

        <table class="list table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="required">*</span>Priority</td>
                    <td><span class="required">*</span>Quantity</td>
                    <td><span class="required">*</span>Price</td>
                    <td><span class="required">*</span>Start date</td>
                    <td><span class="required">*</span>End date</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>    

                <!-- sample row -->
                <tr class="ffSample">    
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control inline" name="product_discounts[0][priority]" value="" size="2" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control inline" name="product_discounts[0][quantity]" value="" size="2" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control inline" name="product_discounts[0][price]" value="" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group date">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control inline" name="product_discounts[0][date_start]" value="" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group date">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control inline" name="product_discounts[0][date_end]" value="" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><a class="ms-button-delete" title="Delete"></a></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary ffClone">Define a new quantity discount</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I nest my tabs.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9957/

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="nested-tabs">
<li><a href="#root-tab" data-toggle="tab"><b>root</b></a></li>
</ul>


<div class="tab-content">
<div id="root-tab" class="tab-pane">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="nested-tabs">
        <li><a href="#nested" data-toggle="tab"><b>All</b></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="nested" class="tab-pane">
        <p>Some Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved it, i was missing a div tag with class tab-content.

Comment: hope my code helped you. can you mark the answer as solved or create your own answer to your question and mark that as solved, thanks.